# Wordpress: Display only category name within The Loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display only the category name within The Loop, without link, markup or anything else. This:

```
<?php the_category(); ?>
```

only gets me the category name as a list object with a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
$category = get_the_category();
echo $category[0]->cat_name;
```